# mysqldump delimited-text and structure

Tags: mysql

I use that for export all data from my_database to delimited-text into one folder

```
mysqldump -u root -p -t -T /path/to/export my_database --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=,
```

All ok. In the /path/to/export I have all data. For each table of my_database I have one .sql file and one .txt file.

But all .sql files are empty (except for tables that have triggers)

**My question is:
Is possible to add some parameters to above command line to export also tables structure in one single job?**

I know that is possible with:

```
mysqldump  --no-data -u root -p my_database > my_database_structure.sql
```

But I hope that is possible to do it in separate files for each table.
One .sql file containing only the structure and one .txt file containing delimited-text data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command with long parameters would be:

```
mysqldump --user=root --password --no-create-info --tab=/path/to/export my_database --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=,
```

Just remove the "--no-create-info" to get the contents of your .sql files populated:

```
mysqldump --user=root --password --tab=/path/to/export my_database --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=,
```

or, if you prefer short options:

```
mysqldump -u root -p -T /path/to/export my_database --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-termaated-by=,
```

Comment: Just playing with the parameters, I have discovered  your second option and I was just trying to answer myself, but you've been faster :)